# Build error on DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o")

Tags: c#, .net-core

Why is .NET Core (version 2.1) throwing a error (not just a warning) on `dotnet build` when I have this in my code

```
var timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
```

> Program.cs(78,8): error CA1305: The behavior of 'DateTime.ToString(string)' could vary based on the current user's locale settings. Replace this call in 'Program.SendMessagesForever(ModuleClient, CancellationToken)' with a call to 'DateTime.ToString(string, IFormatProvider)'.

My understanding was that `"o"` is not local-sensitive anyway?!

Is this desired behavior? If so, how would you work around this? Instantiating a FormatProvider just for this meaningless task seems very unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My understand was that "o" is not local-sensitive anyway?!

It isn't, but the code analysis tool doesn't know that.

From [CA1305: Specify IFormatProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1305-specify-iformatprovider?view=vs-2017):

> When to suppress warnings
>
> It is safe to suppress a warning from this rule when it is certain that the default format is the correct choice, and where code maintainability is not an important development priority.

So you can safely suppress it for `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");`.

Answer (score 7):

Use the static `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` property:

```
var timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o", 
                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: thanks for the short solution! I'll actually go for this in my code as I find it nicer than to put in pragmas. I'm a bit conflicted by I'll go ahead and will accept @CodeCaster's answer though as it actually explains the issue.